# What does `attested to` mean in a legal document?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage, legalese

What does `attested to` mean in a legal context?

> "...are reviewed on a quarterly basis and `attested to` by
>   `<authority-figure>`"

Answer (score 1):

[Attest to:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/attest+to)

> To confirm that something is true.
>
> - I can attest to her whereabouts on the night of the crime—she was with me the entire time.

(The Free Dictionary)